# Simple RSS encoding issue

Tags: php, html, encoding, rss

Consider the following PHP code for getting RSS news on a site I'm developing:

```
<?php
$url = "http://dariknews.bg/rss.php";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$feed_title = $xml->channel->title;
$feed_description = $xml->channel->description;
$feed_link = $xml->channel->link;
$item = $xml->channel->item;

    function getTheData($item){
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $article_title = $item[$i]->title;
        $article_description = $item[$i]->description;
        $article_link = $item[$i]->link;
        echo "<p><h3><a href=".$article_link.">". $article_title. "</a></h3></p><small>".$article_description."</small><p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

The data accumulated by this function should be presented in the following HTML format:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Новини от Дарик</title>
  </head>
   <body>
    <?php getTheData($item);?>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you see I added windows-1251(cyrillic) and utf-8 encoding but the RSS feed is unreadable if I don't change the browser encoding to utf-8. The default encoding in my case is cyrilic but I get unreadable feed. Any help making this RSS readable in cyrilic(it's from Bulgaria) will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested your code and the Bulgarian characters displayed fine when I removed the `charset=windows-1251` meta tag and just left the UTF-8 one. Want to try that and see if it works?

Also, you might want to change your `<html>` tag to reflect the fact that your page is in Bulgarian like this: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="bg" xml:lang="bg">`

Or maybe you need to force the web server to send the content as UTF-8 by sending a Content-Type header:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
?>
```

Just be sure to include this before ANY other content (even whitespace) is sent to the browser. If you don't you'll get the PHP "headers already sent" error.

Comment: I tried what you said but it still doesn't work .My default browser encoding is cyrillic-1251 as every in Bulgaria. If I change the browser encodin to UTF-8 it works.

Comment: That seems to indicate that the your PHP and RSS feed are all fine, it's just a matter of getting the browser to display it as UTF-8. Is it possible that your browser settings might be causing this problem? When I open your script in FireFox or Chrome with the windows-1251 meta tag the page is unreadable, but when I remove that tag and just leave the UTF-8 one it displays properly.

Comment: Every browser in my country should have that type of default encoding not the UTF-8 which makes things difficult.

Comment: @George: Maybe the webserver is sending its own Content-Type header that is setting the page to CP1251. Try adding a header() line to your PHP script to force it to send a UTF-8 Content-Type header (I'll update my answer with an example).

Comment: Sounds reasonable so I should add this line in the begining of the script or in the HTML?

Comment: Either is fine. Just as long as the header() function is called before any other content is sent to the browser. So it can be on the very first line of your HTML file, or in your PHP script. I tested this by putting your PHP script at the top of a PHP file and the HTML part below it, and I added the header function as the last line before the closing PHP tag. The thing is, sometimes the webserver has its own default charset setting that it sends to the browser, regardless of what is set in the HTML meta tag. We're trying to override this by sending a specific charset header in PHP.

Comment: I'll try it. Could you please give a working of example of this issue. I'll upvote your comments because of the effort and good ideas

Comment: I cleared my browsing history and tested that thing again. Now it works really helpful posts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

This can convert to html some characters.

```
$titleEncoded = htmlentities($article_title,ENT_XHTML,cp1251);
```